# How to Change Segment Separator Color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

In my Project i am using segment Controller .. they have four segment in my segment Controller ..My question is I want this background color  and font color and State selected color and separator color[White when select the segment]

Like this Image

[image: Expected segment Controller].

But My screen is

[image: My Original screen]

My code Is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self changeColor];

}
- (void)changeColor{

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:83.0f/255.0f green:198.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0f/255.0f green:197.0f/255.0f blue:197.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [mailboxsegment setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:202.0f/255.0f green:202.0f/255.0f blue:202.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
     UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:09.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                      forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
   [mailboxsegment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

my code i will try to change background color and change font size

Comment: UIColor *selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *deselectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];

for (UIControl *subview in [SegmentRound subviews]) {
    if ([subview isSelected]) 
       [subview setTintColor:selectedColor]; 
    else
       [subview setTintColor:deselectedColor]; 
}

Comment: ok i will try @Birendra

Comment: ok if any issue then tell me

Comment: yeah deafult select first only change white color..if i clicked second segment  or third ,fourth only change segment color in black ..not white

Comment: where did you put this code?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
[self changeColor];

}
- (void)changeColor{ i  apply this code }

Comment: i put the code in -(Void)changecolor method

Comment: you have create action method for UISegmentedControl?

Comment: yes.. see my code above my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132496/discussion-between-birendra-and-user7306261).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
please try this one 

- (void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment 
{ 
    UIColor *selectedColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
    UIColor *deselectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 54/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 

    for (UIControl *subview in [segment subviews]) 
    { 
        if ([subview isSelected]) 
        [subview setTintColor:selectedColor]; 
        else 
        [subview setTintColor:deselectedColor]; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom `segmented control`. But its little complicated to create custom `segmented control` as you will have to provide `images` for `selected` and `deselected` states, 1px `image` for `separator` etc.

Instead of this i will suggest you to use four different `buttons` and apply logic to select only one `button` at a time.

To get effect of `separator` color, place these four `buttons` inside a `stack view` or a normal `UIView` and set background color of that container view to the color which you want to set for `separator`.